# Maven Copied Folder appearing in .War file but not in wtpwebapps folder in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm currently working on a multi-module project in Eclipse, which utilizes an apache tomcat server. The project that contains the web-interface requires a folder from another maven project. Currently to get this folder I'm using a maven resources plugin to get a copy of the desired folder moved over to the project with the web-interface. Looking at just the project explorer I can see the folder has indeed been copied over from the other project. Also when I manually move the .war file for my overall project directly into Tomcat via terminal the project runs fine. However, when I try to run the project from eclipse, it's saying that the it can't find the directory, as while the file got copied into the webapps directory it never got copied into the wtwebapps folder. Has anyone run into a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're going about it the same way.  Rather than copying folders around as part of your build, you should be depending on those resources some other way (e.g. as classpath resources built as part of a JAR your top-level project depends on), which will make WTP, Maven, and everyone else able to find them.

In general, if you're building a build-task that involves manually copying something from somewhere to somewhere else, you're probably doing something wrong.  There are exceptions to every rule so sometimes it's necessary, but it's certainly a code smell and you should always stop and take a careful look at whether there isn't a better way to do what you're trying to do.